# Disabling specific hour on a select day on Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, disable

I am creating a booking system that reserves down to the hour slot using this datetimepicker : https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I am in the process of disabling hours that are already booked but I cannot seem to find the way to do it. In the options, disabling hours just disables those hours for every single day and disable date just disables that date completely.

What I need is: If 06/30/2020 5:00pm is booked, it should be disabled but there is no option to do that. Does anyone have an idea on how to attack this? or is there a datetimepicker with that options?

Thanks.

Comment: In the documentation it says that if you use disabledTimeIntervals() you can disable an specific period of time.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you can implement it like this ->

[Documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#disabledtimeintervals)

```
options = {disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 8 })], [moment({ h: 
18 }), moment({ h: 24 })]] }
```

**EDIT**

[Moment Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/)

Comment: "Will disable times between 12-8am and 6-12pm today." How do I implement this for future intervals? I tried: [moment("2020-07-01 13"),moment("2020-07-01 15")]. and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: The format that you are looking for is
[[moment({y: 2020,M:7,d:1, h: 13 }), moment({ y: 2020,M:7,d:1, h: 15 })]]
that will disable from July first 2020 at 13:00:00: till July first 2020:15:00:00

Comment: no luck on getting it to work. Here is a snippet of my code. [screeny](https://puu.sh/G2Cda/e81b214af5.png)

Comment: I got it to work by using this format: disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment('2020-07-02 12:59:00'), moment('2020-07-02 16:00:00')]] Thank you!